# Is there automatic load balancing in CrateDB?

Tags: cratedb

I am currently evaluating `CrateDB` and came up this question. I know that `CrateDB` proudly claims itself to be a no-config database. So, is there automatic load balancing? Or is it possible to add a load balancer before the dabase?

After browsing the web for a bit I found [this howto](https://statusengine.org/tutorials/cratedb-cluster-ubuntu/) indicating there is no automatic load balancing in CrateDB. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, load balancing happens automatically:

- the client libraries can be configured with multiple nodes and then do round-robin scheduling
- if you pass a query to a node - the execution of the query will happen distributed in the cluster anyhow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there official documentation about this feature?